# Guardar valores de usuários em arquivos no C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, windows-mobile

Estou procurando alguma forma simples para guardar dados do usuário em arquivo no c#.

No Java sempre utilizo a classe [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Estou procurando algo similar no C#, já procurei e achei algumas respostas mas mesmo assim não consegui resolver meu problema.

Por exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908444/is-there-a-c-sharp-analogue-of-java-util-properties-class) se fala muito de "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" e em outras respostas fala sobre "Properties.Settings".

Em [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) tem até alguns exemplos, mas eu não tenho a classe  "ConfigurationManager".

Estou utilizando:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Só que pra min essas classes não estão disponíveis!

Estou utilizando o .net 3.5 e estou desenvolvendo para Windows CE e Windows Mobile.

Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

apesar de por padrão haver algumas classes sobre o namespace `System.Configuration`, estas classes não estam dentro da `System.Configuration`, mas da `System`.

Para utilizar à `ConfigurationManager` você precisa referenciar à `System.Configuration`, para tal utilize o botão direito do mouse sobre `references` e adicione à referencia à `System.Configuration`

Comment: Eu já estou referenciando System.Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo armazenar em um arquivo texto no formato [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html).

Para trabalhar com JSON é muito simples, de uma olhada aqui: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

E não faltam exemplos no site acima e aqui..

Ex de leitura:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp

Ex de escrita:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536818/how-to-write-to-a-json-file-using-c